# How SlingAuthenticationHandler talks to CRXLogin module

Tags: aem, jackrabbit, jcr, sling

I read about this point [here](http://www.connectcon.ch/content/dam/connectWE/Pr%C3%A4sentation_Antonio_Sanso.pdf). But after I could not figure out how the AuthenticationInfo object is passed to CRXLoginModule . What I have understood the flow of SlingAuthenticationHandler is as follows -

1. SlingAuthenticator calls the AuthenticationHandler (the CQ default is TokenAuthenticationHandler)
2. The AuthenticationHandler returns AuthenticationInfo with username and password. In the  code of SlingAuthenticationHandler and it just sends the AuthenticationInfo object from TokenUtil.createCredentials(request, response, this.repository, username, true); The code of TokenUtil class says -

   ```
   adminSession = repository.loginAdministrative(null);

   SimpleCredentials sc = new SimpleCredentials(userId, new char[0]);
   sc.setAttribute(".token", "");
   userSession = adminSession.impersonate(sc);

   TokenCredentials tc = new TokenCredentials((String)sc.getAttribute(".token"));
   AuthenticationInfo authInfo = new AuthenticationInfo("TOKEN", userId);
   authInfo.put("user.jcr.credentials", tc);
   ```
3. adminSession.impersonate(sc) calls org.apache.jackrabbit.core.SessionImpl.impersonate(Credential crd) which again calls org.apache.jackrabbit.core.RepositoryImpl.login and it allows to login and creates token in commit() method of org.apache.jackrabbit.core.security.authentication.DefaultLoginModule .

Questions:

Q1) How is the CRXLoginModule invoked when adminSession.impersonate(sc)  is executed? Which class file is responsible for this?

Q2) I saw the code of SlingAuthenticator but it does not call javax.jcr.RepositoryFactory or com.day.crx.core.CRXRepositoryFactory. How does sling pass the AuthenticationInfo object to CRXLoginModule?

Kindly help me to understand the flow. Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is that nothing that you have listed interacts with CRXLoginModule.

If you refer to the presentation that you linked to, the presentation doesn't mention the CRXLoginModule either.

The reason for this is that `com.day.crx.core.CRXLoginModule` was Day's custom  `javax.security.auth.spi.LoginModule` that was used to interact with the jackrabbit jcr prior to the Authentication mechanism being moved within the OSGi framework, which occurred with CQ 5.5

Rather then using that LoginModule, the Authentication handler uses the Default LoginModule supplied by jackrabbit, which would be the `org.apache.jackrabbit.core.security.authentication.DefaultLoginModule` you've already identified